# Java: Parameterized Runnable

Tags: java, generics, callable

Standard `Runnable` interface has only non-parametrized `run()` method. There is also `Callable<V>` interface with `call()` method returning result of generic type. I need to pass generic parameter, something like this:

```
interface MyRunnable<E> {
  public abstract void run(E reference);
}
```

Is there any standard interface for this purpose or I must declare that basic one by myself?

Comment: If you came over this when working with an **anonymous inner** `Runnable` or `Callable<V>` you cannot and do not need to use parameters. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9273900/1503237) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9273927/1503237) how this can be done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically you would implement `Runnable` or `Callable` with a class that supports a generic input parameter; e.g.

```
public class MyRunnable<T> implements Runnable {
  private final T t;

  public MyRunnable(T t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  public void run() {
    // Reference t.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all three guys who answered my question, all with one same right answer. Should accept all three answers... :)

Comment: Yes :) you are right. I should wait couple of hours for fading answering away.

Answer (score 14):

Java 8 includes the [`java.util.function.Consumer<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface with the single non-default method `void accept(T t)`.

There are many other related interfaces [in that package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 9):

There is also `com.google.common.base.Function<F, T>` from <s>Google Collections</s>[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

If you set the output type to `?` or `Void` (and always have it return `null`) you can use it as an alternative to `Runnable` with an input parameter.

This has the advantage of being able to use `Functions.compose` to transform the input value, `Iterables.transform` to apply it to every element of a collection etc.

Answer (score 3):

Generally if you wanna pass a parameter into the `run()` method you will subclass `Runnable` with a constructor that takes a parameter.

For example,  You wanna do this:

```
// code
Runnable r = new YourRunnable();
r.run(someParam);
//more code
```

You need to do this:

```
// code
Runnable r = new YourRunnable(someParam);
r.run();
//more code
```

You will implement `YourRunnable` similar to below:

```
public class YourRunnable implements Runnable {
    Some param;
    public YourRunnable(Some param){
        this.param = param;
    }
    public void run(){
        // do something with param
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining an interface as done in the original question. Further, avoid weak typing by making the interface specific to what it is supposed to do, rather than a meaning-free interface like `Runnable`.