# can anonymous inner classes extend?

Tags: java, inheritance, concurrency, inner-classes

I want to create an anonymous inner class that extends another class.

What I want to do is actually something like the following:

```
for(final e:list){

        Callable<V> l = new MyCallable(e.v) extends Callable<V>(){
              private e;//updated by constructor
                        @Override
                    public V call() throws Exception {
                        if(e != null) return e;
                        else{
                          //do something heavy
                        }

                    }               
        };
        FutureTask<V> f = new FutureTask<V>(l);     
        futureLoadingtask.run();
        }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Anyway, why don't you want to define a regular class?

Comment: If it is not possible this way I will do it like that

Comment: I recommend to define a regular class here. You must not use anonymous classes just because you _can_. It must be used when It's diminishing code complexity and not enhancing it.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot give a name to your anonymous class, that's why it's called "anonymous". The only option I see is to reference a `final` variable from the outer scope of your `Callable`

```
// Your outer loop
for (;;) {

  // Create some final declaration of `e`
  final E e = ...
  Callable<E> c = new Callable<E> {

    // You can have class variables
    private String x;

    // This is the only way to implement constructor logic in anonymous classes:
    {     
      // do something with e in the constructor
      x = e.toString();
    }  

    E call(){  
      if(e != null) return e;
      else {
        // long task here....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is to scope a local class (not anonymous class) like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
  // ...

  class MyCallable<E> implements Callable<E> {
    public MyCallable(E e) {
      // Constructor
    }

    E call() {
      // Implementation...
    }
  }

  // Now you can use that "local" class (not anonymous)
  MyCallable<String> my = new MyCallable<String>("abc");
  // ...
}
```

If you need more than that, create a regular `MyCallable` class...

Comment: This can not work as I create a series of `Future` in a loop and each may have or may not have `e` set

Comment: @Jim: It could work. I'll update my code. Maybe you should update yours, too to put us in a greater context?

Comment: @Jim: I see. So any type of anonymous, local, or regular inner classes will work for you

Comment: I was trying for anonymous for clarity.I don't want to reuse them.So I can imitate constructor by brackets in your first example?

Comment: @Jim: That's not "imitating a constructor", it is a feature of the Java Language called [Instance Initializers specified in §8.6 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6). An [example can be found here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Class/JavaInstanceInitialization.htm)

Comment: Callable is an interface.So I can not extend it

Comment: So I can declare class variables inside `new Callable` and initialize them in the brackets?

Comment: @Jim: Then use `implements` instead of `extends` in case of local classes. Yes, you can have class variables also in anonymous classes. See the updated example

Answer (score 0):

extends keyword only allow using in class definition. Don't allow in anonymous  class.

Anonymous class define is: **class without any name and don't use after declaration.**

We have to correct your code as following(for example):

```
Callable<String> test = new Callable<String>()
{
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
};
```