# java- add an anonymous class to a field

Tags: java, class, field, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I am trying to understand the use of anonymous class in Java. Basically I've created an anonymous class, i.e. testAnonymous inside a method, then how can I add the anonymous class as a field to its parent class MyClass?

There are problems in my code for sure. I have commented below as well. Hope it helps to explain the question. I can't get my head around this.  Thank you for your help!

```
public class MyClass {
     private int number;
     private String name;
     private Greeting greeting; //the anonymous class FrenchGreeting extends Greeting
     // so is this the way to add the instance of anonymous class? 
     ...
     public void sayHi(){
         Greeting frenchGreeting= new Greeting(){ //created an anonymous class 
            //override some method in Greeting, to make it a french greeting
          }
         frenchGreeting.greet();//why can't I use the method in Greeting class here? 
     }
```

Comment: `private Greeting;` - you're missing a variable name. Try `private Greeting greeting;`

Comment: I think this link could help ...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273900/javacan-annonymous-inner-classes-extend][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273900/javacan-annonymous-inner-classes-extend

Comment: It's best if you show how you override the method. If the method `greet` existing in the base class `Greeting` you can override it in an anonymous class. But new methods cannot be invoked that way except from inside the anonymous class.

Comment: @Eran Thanks. I've edited that but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @Aman I actually looked at that post before posting the question... however I don't understand some of the points i.e. in the response, they say that there shouldn't be a name for anonymous class. I agree. but they also used `Callable<E> c = new Callable<E>` isn't c a name for the anonymous class?

Comment: What errors are you getting?