# how to create an android async task without return statement

Tags: android

I am creating an activity where i want  to use async task to view data thats load from server..

but at a time i want  to set multiple textview data from server values... thats why i dont want any return statement .. but dont know how...please help.. here is my code..

```
private class Downloadbasic extends AsyncTask<void, void, void> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //details code here

    }
 }
```

It giving me error

Comment: the type to use is `Void`, which is an object. Anyway, in an asynctask, there is always a return statement (but there is nothing that prevent you from returning null)

Comment: replace the `void` with `Void`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manipulate UI from `doInBackground`. Return your data to `onPostExecute`, and use the data from there to update your `TextView`s. Or, save them in global variables (not recommended), and use those for the UI, but still from `onPostExecute`.

Comment: publishProgress can also be used if values must be updated during the server work.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your problems:

Your Code:

```
//Here both your return type and parameter are Void and also not written perfectlly
//write Void not void
private class Downloadbasic extends AsyncTask<void, void, void> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

//details code here

  }
}
```

First of all you have to use **Void** not **void** ..anyways

Here your both return type and parameter type are Void but in your `protected String doInBackground( String ... params)`  you used **String** in both cases.. This is the main error .

If you want to create asynctask without return then **return null** must help you here.

Before do anything in AsyncTask just read the [AsyncTask Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  .

And then see this [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194663/extending-asynctaskvoid-void-void).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Downloadbasic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   //details code here

}}
```