# How to stop my app from crashing using AsyncTask in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have built a user interface in Android Studio to test the PSO algorithm in Java. I took this project on from someone else who did it last year, the person before me used AsyncTask with Boolean[] parameters to execute his application. Below is his version of this class, this is because he used a checkbox in his MainActivity that the user can check, so it can either be one or the other.

```
  public class runTests extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
        boolean one    = params[0];
        boolean custom = params[1];

        if (one)
            results = runTest("TestOne");
        else if (custom) {
            double[] re = runTest("customTest");
            if (re != null) results = re;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        pd.dismiss();
        if (results[0] != -1 || results != null) {
            loadIntent(results);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Busy", "Algorithm is currently executing");
    }
}
```

Whereas my code doesn't have a checkbox it only needs to implement one test rather than having the option of two. I just want to run "CustomUseCase" and nothing else. I don't want to use a boolean parameter however I still want to have AsyncTask. Please help me!

```
public class runTests extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Boolean... params) { //sort this out
        boolean one    = params[0];
        boolean custom = params[1];

        if (one)
            results = runTest("CustomUseCase"); //i only want to run this one!!!
        else if (custom) {
            double[] re = runTest("testOne"); //I don't need this, I dont want to run this test
            if (re != null) results = re;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        if(pd!=null){
            pd.dismiss();
            pd = null;
        }
        if (results[0] != -1 || results != null) {
            loadIntent(results);
        }
    }
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(ParticleActivity.this, "Busy", "Algorithm is currently executing");
    }
}
```

Comment: And, why don't you just remove the boolean related code?

Comment: because the parameters are boolean, I'm not the best of java programmers but if im honest, I don't know what to replace it with thats why I asked for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194663/extending-asynctaskvoid-void-void

Comment: Let me recommend you the AsyncTask official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html Try to understand them starting there, they are very easy, and then check the answer by @SamusArin there you have the key.

Comment: As @AlbertoMéndez says, please read the documentation. Here a clue, `AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Void>` it can be read as `AsyncTask<Parameters, Progress, Result> `. So if you don't need to accept a parameter, where only need to do one exact process, you make the parameters as Void. So it becomes `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> `. Try making one class extending AsyncTask, you'll get the feeling.

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez thank you for that, I had a read and understand it better now. I am new to Android Development and Java so i appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change

```
if (results[0] != -1 || results != null) {
    loadIntent(results);
}
```

to

```
if (results != null && results.length > 0 && results[0] != -1) {
    loadIntent(results);
}
```

That is an example of a "**short circuiting**" if statement. The logical AND (&&) operator will cause the entire statement to fail if results is null, otherwise it will evaluate the next logic statement **`results[0] != -1`** with no chance of a NullPointerException.

Try this as well

```
public class runTests extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { //sort this out

        results = runTest("CustomUseCase"); //i only want to run this one!!!
    }
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

> do I return null when executing the doInBackground?

To clarify how the Template Type List (ie, `<Void,Void,Void>`) works, here is an example. Here, we have <**`URL`**, **`Integer`**, **`Long`**>. Notice how doInBackground takes an array of **`URL`** (urls) and returns a **`Long`**, onProgressUpdate takes an **`Integer`** array, and onPostExecute takes a **`Long`**.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         long totalSize = urls.length;
         ...
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

For `<Void, Void, Void>` we would have (empty function argument list "()" corresponds to Void):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected Void doInBackground() {             
         ...
         return;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate() {
         setProgressPercent("hi");
     }

     protected void onPostExecute() {
         showDialog("bye");
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for that, I have done what you told me to do, do I return null when executing the doInBackground? as I still get a return statement error? thanks

Comment: The third type in the "templated type list" (**`<Void, Void, VOID>`**) is the return type, which in this case VOID. You don't need  a return statment, it's implicit, and I should know this but I'm not sure if explicitly returning null from a void function would cause a compile time or runtime error (just comment out the return statement).

Comment: I keep getting windowleaked. After the first curly bracket when you wrote "results = runTest("CustomUseCase")", I don't know what to put there because its asking me for a return statement? otherwise its an error