# Passing parameters to public void run() from the parent

Tags: java, javafx, runnable, java-threads

I'm 50% hopeless :P. I tried (at the beginning) to update the GUI from the code of a Thread, and got NullException. After reading for a while, I understood that the Thread flooded the JavaFX application window and in order for me to update the GUI from a Thread, I need to use the following code:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

            //Update UI here     
            for (int i=0; i<2000;i++)
                {
                 MyMainClass.leftPaneTextArea.appendText("Goodi!\n");
                }

            }
        });
```

So I did use this code, and it indeed allow me to edit the GUI of my main class. However, my question is simple. => this code, which I'm running from a thread, is a code which sits inside a public void run()  (of the thread I run the code from). It looks something like this:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

    String tmpVar;

    ... (Some code)
    ... (Some code)
    ... (Some code)

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

            //Update UI here     
            for (int i=0; i<2000;i++)
                {
                 MyMainClass.leftPaneTextArea.appendText("Goodi!\n");
                }

            }
        });

    ... (Some code)
    ... (Some code)
    ... (Some code)
}
```

How can I pass parameters from the parent's public void run() into this one?.
For example, the String tmpString (I want to pass it on).

Do note that if I declare it outside the public void run() as a static (for example) => I run a lot of threads, so updating a static var might not always be accurate (cause lots of threads will update it simultaneity)

Thank you!.

Comment: Runnable's void run() does not take any parameters nor does it return anything. The values you want to pass on you could store as fields in the parent class, and then in the child class call the parent's fields.

Comment: As long as `tmpVar` is final (or effectively final, which means you only assign it a value once), you can access it in the "inner" `run` method. Can you [edit] the question to make the code you have tried a bit more explicit?

Comment: If you make `tmpVar` `final` you can use it inside your anonymous `Runnable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to think in terms of passing the parameter to the *`Runnable`* object, not to the `run()` method.

If you make the anonymous class an inner class, it becomes pretty clear:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    String tmpVar;

    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)

        Platform.runLater(new Updater(tmpVar));

    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
}

// ...

public static class Updater implements Runnable {

    private final String var ;

    public Updater(String var) {
        this.var = var ;
    }



    @Override 
    public void run() {

        // Access var here

        for (int i=0; i<2000;i++){
            MyMainClass.leftPaneTextArea.appendText("Goodi!\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Now, if `tmpVar` is `final`, or "effectively final<sup>1</sup>", then it will work with your anonymous inner class, and is basically translated to exactly the same thing as the inner class above (in other words, the anonymous inner class gets an implicit field which is populated with the value of the final variable):

```
@Override
public void run() {

    final String tmpVar = ...;

    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

        // access tmpVar here:

        for (int i=0; i<2000;i++)
            {
             MyMainClass.leftPaneTextArea.appendText("Goodi!\n");
            }

        }
    });

    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
}
```

The language designers *could* actually have made this work with non-final variables, but decided that the results would have been too confusing. What would happen would be that it would have been translated to the same inner class seen above: in other words the *current* value of `tmpVar` would have been implicitly passed to a field in the anonymous inner class. This would be a completely new variable, with a different scope, to the one it appears you are accessing, and its value would be a "snapshot" of the value of `tmpVar` at the time the anonymous inner class is created. Having what appears to be one variable that is actually referring to two different variables *potentially with different values* was deemed too confusing and bug-prone.

However, if `tmpVar` is not final (or effectively final): i.e. you are going to assign it values multiple times, you can *explicitly* "snapshot" the value of the variable:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    String tmpVar ;

    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)

    final String varCopy = tmpVar ;

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

        // access varCopy here:

        for (int i=0; i<2000;i++)
            {
             MyMainClass.leftPaneTextArea.appendText("Goodi!\n");
            }

        }
    });

    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
    // ... (Some code)
}
```

(1) "Effectively final" means that the variable is assigned a value *exactly once*. Equivalently, it means you could declare it `final` without creating any compilation errors.

Comment: The solution of declairing it as final and passing it on the the run() works like a charm. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One option, as James_D posted, is using  `final` var inside inner class (anonymous or not)

Anoter options such as `new MyRunnable(someString)` or using `Consumer<T>` you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659986/java-parameterized-runnable)

Comment: You can't pass a `Consumer<T>` to `Platform.runLater(...)` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a getter...

```
public class YourClass {
    private String myVar;

    public void do something(String aVal) {
        myVar= "Value you want to pass";

        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {    
                Log.d("TAG",getMyVar());
            }
        });
    }

    private String myVar(){
        return myVar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do is against overriding rules.
If you were to pass any argument in the `run()` method, you are actually overloading the `run()` method and it will not be called anyway as
when a new thread is created, the no-arg `run()` method is the one called.

I will suggest storing the information somewhere else in a `static` context, and then retrieve it in the `run()` method.

Comment: Overloading? Are you sure?

Comment: if you make a `public void run(String ob){...}` then it is an overload, right?

Comment: I don't think the OP was proposing adding a parameter to the `run()` method though. Creating a `static` variable is a terrible idea, for the reasons pointed out by the OP in the question itself.

Comment: I am not saying making a static variable but someway of storing the information in a static "context".

Comment: And how would that be different?